# I get undefined is not a function when I navigate back to screen when using countdown component

Tags: react-native, expo

I use a counter component. So if I navigate back then I get this error:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

if I remove the counter component then it works. So the problem is from countdown.

Has anyone idea why this error comes ? I use this libary:

https://github.com/talalmajali/react-native-countdown-component

Code:

```
    return (
      <CountDown
        until={10}
        onFinish={() => alert('finished')}
        onPress={() => alert('hello')}
        size={20}
      />
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the onChange prop? I see that some react-native-countdown-component props do not have a default value and 'onChange' is among them.  This could be the cause of the error you see.

```
return (
  <CountDown
    until={10}
    onChange={() => alert('onchange')}
    onFinish={() => alert('finished')}
    onPress={() => alert('hello')}
    size={20}
  />
)
```